# How to create different layout for iPhone and iPad using Autolayout?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

I'am creating a UI for both iPhone and iPad using "Vary for Traits". But I'am getting confuse when to choose Width or Height.[What happen when I select Width or height or both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh7Sg.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will really help to know what the size class constraints mean. See my https://stackoverflow.com/a/52317547/341994 for a summary.

Okay, so what the checkboxes mean depends on what the current traits are for the storyboard you're looking at.

- **First** set the device type  you want to design constraints for, on the left. Now you will see some size classes. If you chose an iPad, the size classes are wR hR. That is width Regular and height Regular.
- So **now** click Vary for Traits. You are about to design some constraints. Which size classes are you about to design? Compare that to what we just said.  If width should be Regular click Width. If height should be Regular click Height.

So for example if you chose an iPad on the left (wR hR) and you now click both Width and Height, that means Regular Regular, which means “I am about to design for iPad.”

But if you chose a small iPhone in portrait on the left (wC hR) you might now click just Width, which means Compact Any, because you don’t care about the height constraint; you just want Compact Width which means “I am about to design for a small iPhone in any orientation.”

Comment: I have filed bugs every year on this. In code, we have horizontal and vertical size classes, so why does the storyboard talk about width and height? And why is this interface so darned confusing? You think in terms of model types and orientations, not in terms of combinations of size classes. It's crazy.

Comment: Just wondering if there is a way to specifically create constraints for landscape iPad and portrait iPad given that they are both (wR hR) ?

Comment: Yes but not via the storyboard.