# Xcode 12, "Vary for Traits" does not work (as expected)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a, relatively, simple layout, which is divided into two main sections, which I've encompassed with two `UIView`s to make it easier to manage.

My goal was to provide two different layouts, one for portrait and one for landscape.

My first idea was to make use of "Vary for Traits" for both "width" and "height", so, I set the storyboard in portrait mode, clicked on "Vary for Traits", I applied the traits I wanted in portrait mode, clicked "Done", switched to landscape mode and repeated the process.

As you can see, switching between the orientations in the storyboard works just fine

[image: Storyboard]

Except, when I run it on a device ... it doesn't work ... as expected

[image: Actual device]

Okay , so I thought, I go back and do it again, but this time just vary for the "width" and yet again, it doesn't work.

So, I then thought, I'd go old school.  I'd add each constraint and set a variant for the specific size class...

[image: Constraints]

(I have different constraints for both orientations, so a single constraint doesn't have a variant for both)

And ... again, this doesn't work.  Before some tells me that "Installed" needs to be ticked for both orientations, no, it doesn't, that just makes Xcode angry and spit lots of nasty comments in the console.

## The "question"

So, the "simple" question is, what am I doing wrong? Have I missed something bleedingly obvious which would make this work, or is having a separate constraint for both portrait and landscape just a really dumb idea (which I though what "Vary for Traits" was basically doing)

## A "hacky" workaround

So, after spending WAY to much time on this, I fell back to an old "workflow" I've used in the past for manually created UIs

Starting from the point of the manually created constraints for each variant, I essentially, placed all of the landscape and portrait constraints into individual `IBOutlet` collections and when `viewWillTransition` was called, manually de/activated the required group of constraints...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var landscapeConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!
    @IBOutlet var portraitConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    enum Orientation {
        case landscape
        case portrait
        case unknown
    }
    
    fileprivate var lastOrientation: Orientation = .unknown
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        updateCurrentConstraints(toSize: view.bounds.size)
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate { (ctx) in
            self.updateCurrentConstraints(toSize: size)
        } completion: { (ctx) in
        }
    }
    
    func updateCurrentConstraints(toSize size: CGSize) {
        var orientation: Orientation = .portrait
        
        if size.width > size.height {
            orientation = .landscape
        }
        
        guard orientation != lastOrientation else { return }
        lastOrientation = orientation

        guard let portraitConstraints = portraitConstraints, let landscapeConstraints = landscapeConstraints else {
            print("No constraits")
            return
        }
        
        var activeConstraints = portraitConstraints
        var inactiveConstraints = landscapeConstraints

        if orientation == .landscape {
            activeConstraints = landscapeConstraints
            inactiveConstraints = portraitConstraints
        }

        for constraint in inactiveConstraints {
            constraint.isActive = false
        }
        for constraint in activeConstraints {
            constraint.isActive = true
        }
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

This works, I wish it didn't and I'm hoping I've just done something seriously stupid ... other then the hacky workaround

If, you don't have much to do and want to muck around with the it, there is a [source repo](https://github.com/RustyKnight/StoryboardBehavingBadly) which I used to test the concept and come up with my "super, awesome" workaround, as I appreciate any kind of storyboard related question is a complete pain in the ... code to work with

Comment: "This works, I wish it didn't and I'm hoping I've just done something seriously stupid ... other then the hacky workaround" It's not hacky. It's quite standard and I would recommend you just do that and be happy. :)

Comment: I played around with your source repo (helps a ton!) and something that I noticed: if you're using the iPhone Pro Max in the Storyboard, it's going to have the RxC and  CxR size classes. However, if you're testing on a device size that's smaller, it'll have CxC for landscape. Running on Pro Max in simulator seems to have no issues. Have you tried out those different scenarios?

Comment: Yeah might help to study info tables here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317545/what-are-the-size-classes-for-the-new-iphone-x-models

Comment: @JoshGrant That's some neat advice.  For the record I'm using iPhone 11" for both the storyboard and device ... because, sanity :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're hitting is that you've set Trait Variations only for `wC hR` and `wR hC` ... so your constraints don't know what to do when you hit a combination such as `wC hC` (iPhone 8 / iPhone SE 2 / etc) or `wR hR` (iPads).

What you want to do is vary your traits **only** for the Height class.

Here is how it can look in Storyboard:

[image]

[image]

If I select the RedView's `width = 175` constraint, the Attributes Inspector shows:

[image]

compared to RedView's `width = 250` constraint:

[image]

Here's the Storyboard source for this layout ... it will handle the device rotation properly, with *NO* code needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="5gV-rv-xrH">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="landscape" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17703"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="HjL-cd-83j">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="5gV-rv-xrH" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="hIj-xH-n33">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="896" height="414"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Q3p-xw-14f" userLabel="LeftButton">
                                <rect key="frame" x="64" y="5.5" width="46" height="30"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.97625964880000005" green="0.85085996409999998" blue="0.83597719680000004" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                            </button>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="This is a title" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="35a-vA-spC" userLabel="TitleLabel">
                                <rect key="frame" x="118" y="0.0" width="660" height="41"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.83216959239999999" green="0.98548370600000001" blue="0.47333085539999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" style="UICTFontTextStyleTitle0"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="OqS-4d-vWh" userLabel="RightButton">
                                <rect key="frame" x="786" y="5.5" width="46" height="30"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.97625964880000005" green="0.85085996409999998" blue="0.83597719680000004" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                            </button>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="TjE-LU-Mo5" userLabel="RedView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="60" y="49" width="175" height="219"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.96804410220000003" green="0.21863630410000001" blue="0.1990364194" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="175" id="FPV-f9-dlF"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="250" id="NhS-uQ-oMA"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="TjE-LU-Mo5" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="0.8" id="PY6-e6-WhI"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <variation key="default">
                                    <mask key="constraints">
                                        <exclude reference="NhS-uQ-oMA"/>
                                    </mask>
                                </variation>
                                <variation key="heightClass=regular">
                                    <mask key="constraints">
                                        <exclude reference="FPV-f9-dlF"/>
                                        <include reference="NhS-uQ-oMA"/>
                                    </mask>
                                </variation>
                            </view>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Y45-dN-gv7" userLabel="YellowView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="243" y="49" width="609" height="344"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.98267000910000002" green="0.80788773300000005" blue="0.061180472370000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="9Rq-n0-LVs"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="Y45-dN-gv7" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="9Rq-n0-LVs" secondAttribute="leading" id="6IU-UQ-CvM"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="TjE-LU-Mo5" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="35a-vA-spC" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="BpX-Pw-rla"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="35a-vA-spC" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Q3p-xw-14f" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="FyN-qU-7qE"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="35a-vA-spC" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="9Rq-n0-LVs" secondAttribute="top" id="G1f-Jl-psr"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Y45-dN-gv7" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="35a-vA-spC" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="KOB-Fp-exO"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="35a-vA-spC" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="hIj-xH-n33" secondAttribute="centerX" id="W6m-QY-p2X"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Y45-dN-gv7" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="TjE-LU-Mo5" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="XLC-WY-foP"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="9Rq-n0-LVs" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Y45-dN-gv7" secondAttribute="bottom" id="esx-I8-2Kb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="TjE-LU-Mo5" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="hIj-xH-n33" secondAttribute="centerX" id="j57-y5-TqD"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="9Rq-n0-LVs" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Y45-dN-gv7" secondAttribute="trailing" id="lLd-bZ-wF2"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Q3p-xw-14f" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="35a-vA-spC" secondAttribute="centerY" id="m4s-gF-g1G"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="OqS-4d-vWh" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="35a-vA-spC" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="quQ-DP-nmi"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="9Rq-n0-LVs" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="OqS-4d-vWh" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="uDD-sD-XqW"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Q3p-xw-14f" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="9Rq-n0-LVs" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="wgq-II-OyY"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="OqS-4d-vWh" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="35a-vA-spC" secondAttribute="centerY" id="wyP-rt-5dh"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Y45-dN-gv7" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="TjE-LU-Mo5" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="xQD-Ne-8vP"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="TjE-LU-Mo5" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="9Rq-n0-LVs" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="zcb-xN-hZU"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <variation key="default">
                            <mask key="constraints">
                                <exclude reference="j57-y5-TqD"/>
                                <exclude reference="xQD-Ne-8vP"/>
                                <exclude reference="6IU-UQ-CvM"/>
                            </mask>
                        </variation>
                        <variation key="heightClass=regular">
                            <mask key="constraints">
                                <exclude reference="zcb-xN-hZU"/>
                                <include reference="j57-y5-TqD"/>
                                <exclude reference="KOB-Fp-exO"/>
                                <include reference="xQD-Ne-8vP"/>
                                <exclude reference="XLC-WY-foP"/>
                                <include reference="6IU-UQ-CvM"/>
                            </mask>
                        </variation>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="AZb-ld-i79" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="74.400000000000006" y="908.09595202398805"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: BUT, I hit this issue if I'm using a wC/hR device, when it's rotated.  I setup the constraints using a iPhone 11 in the storyboard and tested it on a physical iPhone 11 device.  However, your point is still valid, just not for this particular problem, as far as I can see

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Are you saying the layout I gave you does **not** work? It works for me on any simulator, as well as the 3 phones I have: `7` (wC hR / wC hC),  `11 Pro` (wC hR / wC hC). and `Xr` (wC hR / wR hC) ... the `Xr` should be the same as `11`.

Comment: Actually I was just saying that I used both a 11 in the storyboard AND physical device for testing, on the physical device it failed to work - any reason why that should happen?  If I could fix that, I'd be more welcome to adjust the constraints for wC/wC .. and iPads as well :P